# How do I read a random line from one file?

Tags: python

Is there a built-in method to do it? If not how can I do this without costing too much overhead?

Comment: Thanks, I also found this help a lot: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2007-July/055635.html
You have to read them into memory though.

Comment: how does one index a random line without loading the entire file into memory?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Not built-in, but algorithm `R(3.4.2)` (Waterman's "Reservoir Algorithm") from Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming" is good (in a very simplified version):

```
import random

def random_line(afile):
    line = next(afile)
    for num, aline in enumerate(afile, 2):
        if random.randrange(num):
            continue
        line = aline
    return line
```

The `num, ... in enumerate(..., 2)` iterator produces the sequence 2, 3, 4...  The `randrange` will therefore be 0 with a probability of `1.0/num` -- and that's the probability with which we must replace the currently selected line (the special-case of sample size 1 of the referenced algorithm -- see Knuth's book for proof of correctness == and of course we're also in the case of a small-enough "reservoir" to fit in memory ;-))... and exactly the probability with which we *do* so.

Comment: I've always thought that the `random.choice()` function should work on arbitrary iterators as well as sequences, implementing exactly the above algorithm.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill, that would be nice but every tenth question would then be "where did my iterator go"

Comment: @aaron, right -- same reason, e.g., there is no `len` for iterators... the "algorithm" is not hard to see, but consuming the iterator is considered a too-often-surprising effect. It's a series of hard design decisions, of course (e.g., `sum` _does_ consume the iterator -- the decision there is that the summation may well be all the user requires while the length or one random item is less likely to be so... always iffy decisions either way -- if we had a way to clearly mark a name as "having side effects", like Ruby's trailing bang, the design choices might be different).

Comment: @Henry, right - edited the A to attribute it properly, tx for the reminder.

Comment: Gives me `StopIteration` exception on `line = next(afile)` (Python 3.8) (on second call)

Comment: When you call the function a second time on the same iterator (e.g. the same open file) the iterator will have been entirely consumed by the first call, so it will now be empty and StopIteration is correct, just like for any other empty iterator. If you need to *repeatedly* get a random item from an iterator, you must first copy the whole iterator into a list of items, then random.choice on the list is simplest.

Comment: Why the special treatment for the first line? If you start enumerating with 1, you don't need the extra `line = next(afile)`.

Answer (score 54):

```
import random
lines = open('file.txt').read().splitlines()
myline =random.choice(lines)
print(myline)
```

For very long file:
seek to random place in file based on it's length and find two newline characters after position (or newline and end of file). Do again 100 characters before or from beginning of file if original seek position was <100 if we ended up inside the last line.

However this is over complicated, as file is iterator.So make it list and take random.choice (if you need many, use random.sample):

```
import random
print(random.choice(list(open('file.txt'))))
```

Comment: If the task is to read just a line, it doesnt make sense to load the full file into memory.

Comment: This solution is simple and trivial to understand. I would recommend this solution as a final answer.

Comment: This is a valid solution but it wouldn't strip \r\n or EOL. You need to add .rstrip() to  clean it up

Comment: are you loading the entire file into memory? It would be nice to comment on this sort of thing as @iankit has commented about it.

Comment: I like this one since it doesn't matter that you load the whole file in your memory if your pc is made after 2000

Answer (score 18):

It depends what do you mean by "too much" overhead. If storing whole file in memory is possible, then something like

```
import random

random_lines = random.choice(open("file").readlines())
```

would do the trick.

Answer (score 17):

Although I am four years late, I think I have the fastest solution. Recently I wrote a python package called [linereader](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/linereader/1.0.0), which allows you to manipulate the pointers of file handles.

Here is the simple solution to getting a random line with this package:

```
from random import randint
from linereader import dopen

length = #lines in file
filename = #directory of file

file = dopen(filename)
random_line = file.getline(randint(1, length))
```

The first time this is done is the worst, as linereader has to compile the output file in a special format. After this is done, linereader can then access any line from the file quickly, whatever size the file is.

If your file is very small (small enough to fit into an MB), then you can replace `dopen` with `copen`, and it makes a cached entry of the file within memory. Not only is this faster, but you get the number of lines within the file as it is loaded into memory; it is done for you. All you need to do is to generate the random line number. Here is some example code for this.

```
from random import randint
from linereader import copen

file = copen(filename)
lines = file.count('\n')
random_line = file.getline(randint(1, lines))
```

I just got really happy because I saw someone who could benefit from my package! Sorry for the dead answer, but the package could definitely be applied to many other problems.

Comment: I had ValueError line no. not found, but line no. was less than size of the file.

Comment: Cool stuff! Is there a reason you index file lines beginning with 1? (getline(file, 0) returns the last line)

Comment: Strangely enough, in my ab testing this was an order of magnitude slower than just seeking to a random line like `for _ in range(randint(1, length) ): | line = file.readline()`

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to load the whole file into RAM with `f.read()` or `f.readlines()`, you can get random line this way:

```py
import os
import random


def get_random_line(filepath: str) -> str:
    file_size = os.path.getsize(filepath)
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            pos = random.randint(0, file_size)
            if not pos:  # the first line is chosen
                return f.readline().decode()  # return str
            f.seek(pos)  # seek to random position
            f.readline()  # skip possibly incomplete line
            line = f.readline()  # read next (full) line
            if line:
                return line.decode()  
            # else: line is empty -> EOF -> try another position in next iteration
```

P.S.: yes, that was proposed by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams in his answer above, but a) there's no code in his answer and b) I've come up with this implementation myself; it can return first or last line. Hope it may be useful for someone.

However, if you care about distribution, this code is not an option for you.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly improved version of the Alex Martelli's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540315/244297), which handles empty files (by returning a `default` value):

```
from random import randrange

def random_line(afile, default=None):
    line = default
    for i, aline in enumerate(afile, start=1):
        if randrange(i) == 0:  # random int [0..i)
            line = aline
    return line
```

This [approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) can be used to get a random item from any iterator using `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to read over the entire file, you can seek into the middle of the file, then seek backwards for the newline, and call `readline`.

Here is a Python3 script which does just this,

*One disadvantage with this method is short lines have lower likelyhood of showing up.*

```
def read_random_line(f, chunk_size=16):
    import os
    import random
    with open(f, 'rb') as f_handle:
        f_handle.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        size = f_handle.tell()
        i = random.randint(0, size)
        while True:
            i -= chunk_size
            if i < 0:
                chunk_size += i
                i = 0
            f_handle.seek(i, os.SEEK_SET)
            chunk = f_handle.read(chunk_size)
            i_newline = chunk.rfind(b'\n')
            if i_newline != -1:
                i += i_newline + 1
                break
            if i == 0:
                break
        f_handle.seek(i, os.SEEK_SET)
        return f_handle.readline()
```

Answer (score 1):

Seek to a random position, read a line and discard it, then read another line. The distribution of lines won't be normal, but that doesn't always matter.

Comment: In particular, this makes it impossible to ever select the first line (as well as picking other lines with a probability proportional to the length of each previous line).  My A doesn't produce a normal distribution either (that would be weird -- what mean, what variance?!), but a uniform one, which seems somewhat more likely to meet the OP's meaning for "random".

Comment: To overcome the problem pointed by @AlexMartelli, Choose the first line in case the random seek leads you to the last line. But another issue here is that a line having relatively more words to other lines will have higher probability of getting selected.

Answer (score 1):

This may be bulky, but it works I guess? (at least for txt files)

```
import random
choicefile=open("yourfile.txt","r")
linelist=[]
for line in choicefile:
    linelist.append(line)
choice=random.choice(linelist)
print(choice)
```

It reads each line of a file, and appends it to a list. It then chooses a random line from the list. 
If you want to remove the line once it's chosen, just do

```
linelist.remove(choice)
```

Hope this may help, but at least no extra modules and imports (apart from random) and relatively lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print (random.choice(lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, a little like Philip Hughes' explanation, but with an addition of `.strip` in case you are collecting a random line that needs extra space cleaning or for jumping rows.

Code:

```
import random

def random_line():
    file = open("file.txt", "r")
    text = []

    for line in file:
        line = line.strip() 
        text.append(line)

    file.close()

    x = random.randrange(0,len(text))
    return x
```

It does the following: imports the random module, reads a file, creates a list with the extracted and "cleaned" lines from that file (.txt in this case), closes the file, and selects a random item (that was a line in the .txt) from the created list.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, just has a tiny bias due to the tiny chance of the max occurring more than once, in which case the first occurrence wins.

```
from random import random

def random_line(afile):
    return max(afile, key=lambda _: random())
```

Faster reservoir sampling than [Alex's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540315/12671057) if you're ok with holding `batchsize` lines in memory:

```
from itertools import islice
from random import randrange, choice

def random_line(afile, batchsize=1024):
    n = 0
    while lines := list(islice(afile, batchsize)):
        k = len(lines)
        n += k
        if randrange(n) < k:
            line = choice(lines)
    return line
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add the lines into a set() which will change their order randomly.

```
filename=open("lines.txt",'r')
f=set(filename.readlines())
filename.close()
```

To find the 1st line:

```
print(next(iter(f)))
```

To find the 3rd line:

```
print(list(f)[2])
```

To list all the lines in the set:

```
for line in f:
    print(line)
```