# How do i choose random string from python list other than using random.randint() in index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I am trying to retrieve a random string from python list to build a word guess challenge. I deployed anaconda environment on Alibaba Cloud ECS Instance.

I often use the following method to retrieve a random string from the list.

Let's say

```
WordStack=['A','B','C','D']
print(WordStack[random.randint(len(WordStack))])
```

Is there any optimized way or build-in funtion to do that? Due to a large number of words, it takes some time to give the result.

Comment: Both those operations have O(1) complexity (list's get item and randint). I doubt using a long list would make much of a difference.

Comment: Exactly. The slowness must come from other parts of your code.

Comment: @ayhan and `len` is also O(1)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes, that too. It seems random.choice is implemented pretty much the same way: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L278

Comment: if loading is the slow part; think about using a different file format or tricks like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28254628/1358308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) which does exactly what you need. For your case, it would look like this:

```
WordStack = ['A','B','C','D']
random_str = random.choice(WordStack)
print(random_str)  # -> whatever
```

---

Having said that, I wouldn't expect it to make such a big difference on the speed of the process. But If I find the time I will test it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try random.randrange() instead of random.randint().

random.randrange():

> Return a randomly selected element from range(start, stop, step). This is equivalent to choice(range(start, stop, step)), but **doesn’t actually build a range object.**

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange

I am not aware of any built-in function that does this.

So the equivalent statement would be:

`WordStack[random.randrange(len(WordStack))]`