# Select random line in txt file with Python

Tags: python, random, text-files

I want to use Python to output a random line from an external .txt file.
In this .txt file there are several sentences. But each of them is in a different line.

My approach is to generate a random line number:

```py
import random

line = random.randint(1, max_line)

#max_line stands for the number of lines in the .txt file.
```

and then to reproduce this line using print().

I've already looked around a bit, but haven't found anything yet regarding outputting the sentence of the line. Any idea how I could make this work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540288/how-do-i-read-a-random-line-from-one-file

Comment: @NC101 Got it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to use is .readlines(). This could work like this:

```
line = random.randint(1, max_line)

with open("external_file.txt", "r") as file:
    print(file.readlines()[line]
```

Replace "external_file.txt" with your actual filename.

Although, if you want to include the first line of the file as well, you might want to change `line = random.randint(1, max_line)`to `line = random.randint(0, max_line)`