# How do I print a random full link from a text file?

Tags: python, file, random, text-files, readline

In the text file "unt.txt" there's 38 links all on their own lines. How do I print a random link from the file? This code below just returns a random amount of characters in a link and not the entire link.

```
from os import close, read
import random

rnd_num = random.choice(range(1,39))

File = open("unt.txt", "r")
print (File.readline(rnd_num))
File.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read a random line from one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540288/how-do-i-read-a-random-line-from-one-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
lines = open('text.txt').read().splitlines()
line = random.choice(lines)
print(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
with open("unt.txt","r") as f:
    urls = f.readlines()

import random

print(random.choice(urls))
```